# Self assign in constructor of java

Tags: java

I have a class like this:

```
public class Reza {
    public Reza(Reza reza) {

    }
}
```

I want to replace reza of input parameter of constructor to current object like this:

```
this = reza
```

How can i do?
is it possible?

Comment: It is not possible. But the question is why would you do that? Or what do you think, it should do?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make a (static) `clone()` method ?

Comment: You want this why? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. `this` and `reza` represent different objects; you cannot replace the object being created in a constructor with an existing one.

However, you can *copy* the content of `reza` into `this`. For that, add a series of assignments like this:

```
public Reza(Reza reza) {
    field1 = reza.field1;
    field2 = reza.field2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Impossible, but you can copy all your properties one by one (like other answer) or by reflection.
Something like this, hoping that you have getters and setters for the properties you mean to copy (I copied it from another stackoverflow answer and it looks correct):

```
public Reza(Reza reza) {
    Method[] gettersAndSetters = reza.getClass().getMethods();

    for (int i = 0; i < gettersAndSetters.length; i++) {
            String methodName = gettersAndSetters[i].getName();
            try{
              if(methodName.startsWith("get")){
                 this.getClass().getMethod(methodName.replaceFirst("get", "set") , gettersAndSetters[i].getReturnType() ).invoke(this, gettersAndSetters[i].invoke(reza, null));
                    }else if(methodName.startsWith("is") ){
                        this.getClass().getMethod(methodName.replaceFirst("is", "set") ,  gettersAndSetters[i].getReturnType()  ).invoke(this, gettersAndSetters[i].invoke(reza, null));
                    }

            }catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that.  `this` is, by design, a read-only constant.  Assigning to it doesn't make any sense.